# Spring : injecting data object in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, entity

As JPA and Spring have different context management, it is not recommended to create a data object class with both annotations @Component and @Entity.

But without @Component data object can't be injected into a service by @Autowired.

But creating new instance of my data object with new seems like a regression for me.

Is there a good way to inject a data object (@Entity) in a spring managed service ?

Data object :

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserDo {
//data object stuff ...
```

Service :

```
@Service("listAllGoods")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ListAllGoods implements IListGoodService{

@Autowired
private IGoodDao goodDao;

@Autowired
private UserDo user;

//option 1 : works but not recommended because forces @Component on data object
@Override
public List<GoodDo> createGood() {
    user.setName("Roger");
    return goodDao.create(user);
}

//option 2 : 
// without @Autowired UserDo
// regression feeling
@Override
public List<GoodDO> createGood() {
    UserDo user = new UserDo();
    user.setName("Roger");
    return goodDao.create(user);
}
```

Comment: in general, it is a bad practice to introduce data objects as beans. consider using @Component/@Repository/@Service only for functional components which are performing units of work.

Comment: Do you want new user object every time you referenced the field? Also, please translate your code into English.

Comment: Translated. @Maxim Manco : I totally agree, but that's the point. But I need to create an entity object to persist in the service. I just would like to avoid the use of new.

Comment: What you consider a regression is the correct thing to do: every time you create a user, by definition, you want a new user. Not the same one as the one you "created" (or rather, modified) before. What you think works doesn't work at all. Call createGood() twice in a row, and you will still have only one UserDo. Dependency injection is not, at all, about avoiding using new. It's about injecting functional dependencies in order to make the code testable (and use AOP, etc.).

Comment: @Artem Malchenko I need new instance of user each time service is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main feature of Spring is dependency injection.

> **Dependency** or coupling, a state in which one object
>   uses a function of another object

It's clear that `User` entity is not a dependency in your situation, so it's the most correct approach to create it with a `new` operator.

---

Also, you said that you want your "dependency" to be created every time you reference your service. It's the "How to update prototype bean in a singleton" problem which you can encounter on an interview. It's not in the scope of your question, but I highly recommend you to google this.